# Issue With Get Boundingbox Object Use Model Properties API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I have issue when try get boundingbox use BIM 360/ACC Model Properties API, the result of bboxMin and bboxMax not correct when I compare with the real model use Revit API, and this is ouput from Model Properties API with element `01cc79a0-b442-46a7-aa28-7591b3806a60-0057a0f6`

```
[
  {
    "svf2Id": 1558,
    "otgId": 1558,
    "lineageId": "2bb621b2",
    "externalId": "01cc79a0-b442-46a7-aa28-7591b3806a60-0057a0f6",
    "lmvId": 17777,
    "databaseId": "836ca369",
    "props": {
      "p01bbdcf2": "FAB_LEVEL 1",
      "p0337db30": true,
      "p09faf620": "EqTee",
      "p13b6b3a0": "EqTee",
      "p153cb174": "MW_M_PipeEqTee_CS [5742838]",
      "p20d8441e": "Pipe Fittings",
      "p240c30c1": "3bf616f9-6b98-4a21-80ff-da1120c8f6d6",
      "p2b38e630": 1299.9999999552597,
      "p2c0bde18": "Other",
      "p30db51f9": "MW_M_PipeEqTee_CS",
      "p3c57b64e": "New Construction",
      "p3f78b271": 90.0,
      "p42881968": 30.15,
      "p4709f0b8": "50 mmø-50 mmø-50 mmø",
      "p51721b83": "Tee",
      "p51fa5281": 50.0,
      "p5ea8a655": 0.0,
      "p5eddc473": "Revit Pipe Fittings",
      "p682199ff": 0.0,
      "p8571457c": "level-1",
      "p875a6521": "50 mmø-50 mmø-50 mmø",
      "p98057bd5": "RUWT",
      "p9b4eb664": false,
      "pa06a928b": 63.50000000000001,
      "pa7275c45": -2008049,
      "pab5862eb": "M_PipeRUWT",
      "pae6de8dc": 90.0,
      "paec306c1": false,
      "pb2bb8b86": 25.0,
      "pb790e1f6": "M_PCWT_FAB_PCWR",
      "pc1107d2e": 0.0,
      "pdcd11637": 0.0,
      "pe36ff9a6": "RUWT 7",
      "pe7bd3497": 0.0,
      "pee815a7f": "None",
      "pf2274dd8": 24.119999999999997,
      "pfa74ec17": "MW_EqTee_ButtWelded_CS",
      "pfdf3d1f1": 60.3,
      "pfe4526bc": 63.50000000000001
    },
    "propsHash": "823f4e04",
    "geomHash": "0sTBVuU4MWT+aez0r4DXZA",
    "bboxMin": {
      "x": 23140.19253646859,
      "y": 48851.27388988427,
      "z": 16.26149963902241
    },
    "bboxMax": {
      "x": 23140.303569470067,
      "y": 48851.37130489879,
      "z": 16.38850002659565
    },
    "views": [
      "59f3eb59",
      "71f6ba26"
    ]
  }
]
```

This is Result from Revit API with element have uniqueid `01cc79a0-b442-46a7-aa28-7591b3806a60-0057a0f6`

```
Max: (-646.243556457, 527.654365464, 4.473425199)

Min: (-646.441391113, 527.347114808, 4.056758527)
```

And this is SurveyPoint :

```
Position: (515.939103522635, -107.490943378868, -49.2946194225724)
SharedPosition: (75909.4355032959, 158948.976680165, 0)
```

Can I know what is exact meaning of **boundingbox** `max` and `min` location in this case return from shared coordinate model ?

Any help apprecited !

Comment: Hi ChungHo, sorry you hit a known question. We have logged it at BIMCAS-13864 (title: Index v2 API: boundingbox data seems to have issue?) to ask engineer team to explain the formula of relationship (with other points such as shared position of Revit).  Index v2 means Model Properties API. We are pushing engineer team to check this ticket. I also append your name to this ticket.

Comment: Thank for your anwser, I guess at the moment default unit is meter in output bbmax and bbmin with shared coordinate, please help me recheck it , thank you.